# How I can Display my Route with OSM ?

Tags: android, openstreetmap, routes

Hey I search in Google and in Stackoverflow and I find some things but it doesn't help.
So this is my first time I work with OSM and now I have two Geopoints and what to display the Route.

Have someone good links oder tut? 
And don't think i am to lazy to search by myself I am searching too.

Answer (score 1):

Pick a [map widget with OSM support](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks#Widgets) (e.g. osmdroid with bonuspack) and add a vector layer with your route.

Comment: Thank u. I have allready include the osmbonuspack. I thought i can use the Marker and Roadmanager to show the route. Have u some link were is the vector layer used to see how this one is created. (MY English ist not so good..sorry)

Comment: 'vector layer' is a general term for that kind of semi-GIS frameworks meaning that you can add primitives with georeference on top.  
Sorry, I don't have any experience with Android. I recommend to make use of the official support channels for the dedicated products.